# How to make a 'recently viewed' items in codeigniter (v2)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session, frameworks

Can anyone suggest the best solution for creating a recently viewed items/pages logic using codeigniter? I'd prefer to use the codeigniter sessions rather than the standard $_SESSION if possible.

Also - to add to session but once I hit 10 items in the array to remove the oldest item in the array.

Comment: Does anyone how I would do the equivalent to this in codeigniter
$_SESSION['recent'][] = $var;

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html It's easy from there on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $recentlyViewed = $this->session->userdata('recentlyViewed');
    if(!is_array($recentlyViewed)){
        $recentlyViewed = array();  
    }
    //change this to 10
    if(sizeof($recentlyViewed)>3){
        array_shift($recentlyViewed);
    }
    //here set your id or page or whatever
    if(!in_array($data['id'],$recentlyViewed)){
        array_push($recentlyViewed,$data['id']);
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('recentlyViewed', $recentlyViewed);    
    $recentlyViewed = array_reverse($recentlyViewed);
    //var_dump($recentlyViewed);
```

Now use a foreach on recentlyViewed with an or_where query

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as like the original poster, this did exactly what I needed it to do, thank you.

Comment: agreed this is a nice way of doing this @Paul501 thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this approach will work for you, but you could dump that kind of data into a SQL database with a timestamp and then use the "Ascending"/"Descending" property of a SQL query in conjunction with a "limit(10)" property... it might be too much effort for what you are trying to accomplish, but you could also sync the query data with your CI session object?  Dunno, just a thought :D